# options binding broken after applying css class

Tags: css, knockout.js

Knockout (2.2.1) options binding for  was working ok but broken silently after some css class was applied to outer div.

```
<div class="class1 class2"> <select data-bind="options: months, ...
```

If I include 'class2', browser does not complain anything but drop down list is empty..

[Edit] My knockout view model is working ok, I am not asking about it, it provides months like 01, 02, ... as you can imagine and drop down list shows them on click. But with 'class2', it shows nothing, just empty. Our company is outsourcing for css stuff.

And for 'class2',

```
$(".class2 select").chosen({width: '300px'});
```

[Edit 2] It turns out that jquery plug-in 'Chosen' hasn't been set up properly and that caused empty .

Comment: Please add more context! What is class1 and class2? What do you mean on broken? etc.

Comment: Please explain little more. Can I see what content is in class1 and class2?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute is called *data-bind* not *data-binding*